# Can something 'suggest' that something else is 'certainly the case'?

Tags: semantics

Is a sentence such as the one below semantically acceptable?

> These circumstances suggest that our society is certainly changing.

Comment: Reads okay. You mean *suggesting* is vague and *certainly* is decisive? Slight exaggeration. Writer must have been human.

Comment: Thanks. I think my concerns are late-night writer's insanity taking hold! How about 'Events suggest that this is certainly a period of change'? Does that get a semantic green light from you?

Comment: If this is *your* writing, I'd take the opportunity to fix the contradiction—maybe "certainly" can be replaced by a more useful adverb? If it's someone else's I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: Thanks, Andy. The problem is I used a similar construction in a published piece. It is locked in print forever! I am now curious/anxious to know if it is a semantically sound construction.

Comment: It's J.K. Rowling here, by the way (just lightening the mood a little). Thoughts from fellow language lovers would be appreciated.

Comment: Two mutually exclusive modal usages. Suggest 'strongly suggest'.